# How to bind the object itself to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Within a `DataGrid` one can bind a property to a column. For example:

```
Binding="{Binding MyProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
```

Is it possible to bind the object itself to the column (not the property only)?

The reason behind this question is, that the converter `MyConverter` needs more information of the whole object to display the property correctly. When using a binding like `Binding MyProperty` the converty only gets the property information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave away the path information:

```
Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
```

or alternatively use an `IMultiValueConverter` and bind the different properties you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
```

or

```
Binding="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
```